# Why is my removeNumbersLessThan function not working properly?

Tags: javascript, object

I have to write a function that takes a number and an object and input and return an object that has removed all numbers less than the indicated number.

I completed a similar function on the previous problem in the problem set that did the opposite, removeNumbersGreaterThan. All I really did was copy that same code that worked on the previous problem and replaced the greater than symbol with a less than symbol, but for some reason it is not working in all cases.

I've already tried changing it to less than or equal to <= but that made no difference at all. Not sure what's going on!

```js
function removeNumbersLessThan(num, obj) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < Object.keys(obj).length) {
    if (Object.values(obj)[i] < num) {
      delete obj[Object.keys(obj)[i]]
    }
    i++;
  }
  return obj;
}

//test
var obj = {
  a: 4,
  b: 6,
  c: 5,
  d: 3
}

removeNumbersLessThan(7, obj)
console.log(obj)

//returns b:6 d:3 -- should return empty object
```

I noticed it returns the second value no matter what. Even if it is less than the num value.
After adding some more elements to my object, I noticed that it skips over every other element in the object.
I also found that the reason by previous opposite function worked was because the tests skipped over these cases. It also has the same issue, upon further investigation.

Comment: Note, it would be better if you use [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over the object's keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your loop deletes a value from `obj`, that key will no longer be returned from `Object.keys`.
But you still increment the `i` counter, so you "skip" a key every time you delete a key from `obj`.

You can fix this by only getting the objects keys once and storing them before deleting properties:

```js
function removeNumbersLessThan(num, obj) {
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
  for (let key of keys) {
    if (obj[key] < num) {
      delete obj[key];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

//test
var obj = {
  a: 4,
  b: 6,
  c: 5,
  d: 3
};
removeNumbersLessThan(7, obj);
console.log(obj);
```

If you don't want to mutate the object, you could instead copy all properties that are greater than or equal to a new object:

```js
function removeNumbersLessThan(num, obj) {
  let result = {};
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj))
    if(value >= num)
      result[key] = value;
  return result;
  }

let obj = {
  a: 4,
  b: 6,
  c: 5,
  d: 3,
  e: 8
};
console.log(removeNumbersLessThan(7, obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

You mutate the object and get in every loop with a deleted property a new lenght in this vase the index is one ahead.

This solution is not advisable, because you get for every iteration new keys and values.

```js
function removeNumbersLessThan(num, obj) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < Object.keys(obj).length) {
        if (Object.values(obj)[i] < num) {
            delete obj[Object.keys(obj)[i]];
        } else {
            i++; // increment only if not deleted
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

var obj = { a: 4, b: 6, c: 5, d: 3 };

removeNumbersLessThan(7, obj);
console.log(obj); // {}
```

Instead you could get the keys with a [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Then check with this key.

```js
function removeNumbersLessThan(num, object) {
    for (let key in object) {
        if (object[key] < num) {
            delete object[key];
        }
    }
    return object;
}

var obj = { a: 4, b: 6, c: 5, d: 3 };

removeNumbersLessThan(7, obj);

console.log(obj); // {}
```

Comment: While correct, this doesn't address the "why" portion of OP's question - the mutation of the underlying list during iteration :)

Answer (score 1):

First, note that when you delete a `key` on the object (i.e you mutate the object), the `length` property of the array returned by `Object.keys()` will decrease in every iteration, at the same time you increment the `i` variable on every iteration, so in the end you will not traverse all the properties of the object.

In this particular case, I will prefer using [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to traverse the objects keys instead of your `while` loop, using the next logic:

```js
function removeNumbersLessThan(num, obj)
{
    for (const key in obj)    
    {
        if (obj[key] < num)
            delete obj[key];
    }

    return obj;
}

console.log(removeNumbersLessThan(7, {a:4, b:6, c:5, d:3}));
console.log(removeNumbersLessThan(5, {a:4, b:6, c:5, d:3}));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce version...

```
function removeNumbersLessThan(num, obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((accum, next) => {       
        if (obj[next] >= num)
          return {...accum, [next]: obj[next]};
        else
          return accum;
  },{});
}

      //test
      var obj = {
        a:4,
        b:6,
        c:5,
        d:3
      } 

let x = removeNumbersLessThan(7,obj);

console.log(x);
```